# Package json dependencies don't match

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, package.json

I'm confused by behavior in NPM / package.json file and the packages dependencies.  An example is on the package `gulp-watch`.  When we look at its package.json file [on github](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/blob/master/package.json) we see it has a dependency on `"anymatch": "^3.1.1"`.  But when I pull in the  `"gulp-watch": "^5.0.1"` package and take a look in the `yarn.lock` file, I see this:

```
gulp-watch@^5.0.1:
  version "5.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/gulp-watch/-/gulp-watch-5.0.1.tgz#83d378752f5bfb46da023e73c17ed1da7066215d"
  integrity sha512-HnTSBdzAOFIT4wmXYPDUn783TaYAq9bpaN05vuZNP5eni3z3aRx0NAKbjhhMYtcq76x4R1wf4oORDGdlrEjuog==
  dependencies:
    ansi-colors "1.1.0"
    anymatch "^1.3.0"
    chokidar "^2.0.0"
    fancy-log "1.3.2"
    glob-parent "^3.0.1"
    object-assign "^4.1.0"
    path-is-absolute "^1.0.1"
    plugin-error "1.0.1"
    readable-stream "^2.2.2"
    slash "^1.0.0"
    vinyl "^2.1.0"
    vinyl-file "^2.0.0"
```

Where its pulling in `anymatch "^1.3.0"`.

I've deleted both node-modules and the yarn.lock file and it doesnt seem to change things.

I'm curious why there is a difference there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're looking at the most recent version of `package.json`, which has [updated dependencies](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/commit/39e30a2bc5eb229229bf8cbbebbd6d77c5e34025#diff-7ae45ad102eab3b6d7e7896acd08c427a9b25b346470d7bc6507b6481575d519) since the release of 5.1.0. The [`package.json` during the release of 5.1.0](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/blob/v5.0.1/package.json) specifies `"anymatch": "^1.3.0"`, which is why you see the results you see.

Comment: I see, so it appears this is code that was merged into master but has not been released, and the PR author did not bump version number.  Thats what was confusing me.  I saw the package versions were the same, but the contents were different.  Thanks for the clarification!